# Change "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to this page" screen

Tags: google-chrome, internet-connection

Not 100% sure superuser is the stackexchange place for this question but hopefully I'll be redirected otherwise.

I use chrome. I have the setting "On startup, get back to the state I was previously" to reopen my working tabs.

Sometimes when I'm not connected, they all open with the (normal) error message "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to this page"... (in french in the screenshot ...)

[image: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to this page]

I find the screen depressing. Is there a way I could customize it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the Chrome error pages is built into Chrome. The only way you can change them is by changing the code, and rebuild Chromium.

Another approach is to run a proxy server on your machine, that would return an HTML page of your choice upon network error. That way, you can control what you see, and add a less depressing message :)

Comment: I shall consider the second option you suggest! Thanks!

Comment: Which proxy server to install please advise.